# Blank Cell equal to value Zero in another cell should returns True in python,pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is my data in excel format

- Where there is a blank cell it is treating as general
- Where there are amounts, format is "#,##0.00000;(#,##0.00000)"

[image]

I have written the below code to calculate the Blank cell equal to value zero from another cell should return True

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',dtype=str)
df.replace('nan','',inplace=True)
    
df['True']=''
df.loc[df['Amount_1'] == df['Amount_2'],'True'] = 'True'
df.loc[df['Amount_1'] != df['Amount_2'],'True'] = 'False'
df

    Name    Amount_1    Amount_2    True
0   A1                     0        False
1   A2          0                   False
2   A3                     0.01     False
```

If I am doing it in excel I am getting `True` for the first two rows whereas I am getting `False` here.

My End Result/Expected Result should be:

1. `True` for A1 and A2 but I am getting `False` instead.
2. While writing to Excel blank cells should come as blanks.

Comment: `df.replace('nan','',inplace=True)` replace to zero, then.

Comment: @Lamanus df.replace('nan', ' ' , inplace = True) is NOT replacing with Zero.

Comment: I know. I mean `nan` to `0`, `df.replace('nan',0,inplace=True)`

Comment: But i want while writing to excel back it should not be printing zero wherever we have blank cell it should come as blank cells only, i have written in expected results point number 2.

Comment: Then simply change the comparison condition to deal the empty with zero. `df.loc[if(df['Amount_1'] == '', 0, df['Amount_1']) == df['Amount_2'],'True'] = 'True'`, might wrong, please check the details.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219024/discussion-between-jatin-kapoor-and-lamanus).

Answer (score 1):

You could give more conditions such as

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv',dtype=str) # this is modified for my test.
df=df.fillna('')

df['True'] = ''
df.loc[df['Amount_1'] != df['Amount_2'], 'True'] = 'False'
df.loc[df['Amount_1'] == df['Amount_2'], 'True'] = 'True'
df.loc[(df['Amount_1'] == '') & (df['Amount_2'] == '0'), 'True'] = 'True'
df.loc[(df['Amount_2'] == '') & (df['Amount_1'] == '0'), 'True'] = 'True'
df
```

where the result is:

```
    Name    Amount_1    Amount_2    True
0   A1                        0     True
1   A2            0                 True
2   A3                     0.01    False
```